# progress bar in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to implement a progress bar in a PowerShell script, the script downloads Windows updates. But there are no loops so I can't do it with a counter. I would like to do it with get-childitem and.

Here is my question, where does PowerShell save files by default, so I can count the downloaded files via the path ?

This is my Code:

```
$Criteria="IsInstalled=0" 
#EE
     $resultcode= @{0="Not Started"; 1="In Progress"; 2="Succeeded"; 
     3="Succeeded With Errors"; 4="Failed" ; 5="Aborted" }

$updateSession = new-object -com "Microsoft.Update.Session"

write-progress -Activity "Updating" -Status "Checking available updates" 
$Searcher = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher 
$updates= $Searcher.Search($Criteria).Updates

if ($Updates.Count -eq 0)  { "There are no applicable updates."}   
else { 

   $downloader = $updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()   
   $downloader.Updates = $Updates  

   $date = get-date
   write-progress -Activity 'Updating' -Status "Downloading $($downloader.Updates.count) updates started at $date"
   $Result= $downloader.Download()  

   if (($Result.Hresult -eq 0) –and (($result.resultCode –eq 2) -or ($result.resultCode –eq 3)) ) {

   $updatesToInstall = New-object -com "Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl"

   $Updates | where {$_.isdownloaded -and $_.title -notlike "*Internet Explorer 9*" -and $_.title -notlike "*Internet Explorer 10*"} | foreach-Object {$updatesToInstall.Add($_) | out-null }
   $installer = $updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
   $installer.Updates = $updatesToInstall


   write-progress -Activity 'Updating' -Status "Installing $($Installer.Updates.count) updates started at $date"
    $installationResult = $installer.Install()
    $Global:counter=-1
    $installer.updates | select Title,EulaAccepted,@{label='Result';
                           expression={$ResultCode[$installationResult.GetUpdateResult($Global:Counter++).resultCode ] }}  
    shutdown.exe /t 5 /r
} 
}
```

Comment: Powershell's "default location" usually is the current directory. File download location, however, might depend on how you do the download. [Edit] the question and show how the updates are being downloaded, that might provide a clue where to look for those.

Comment: I've posted my source code can you help me now